# wordexp_t fails when folder contains a space

Tags: c++

My code:

```
QString clsDebugService::strGetUserFolder(QString strFolder) {
    QString strCopy(strFolder);
    if ( strCopy.isEmpty() ) {
        strCopy = "~";
    }
    const QChar cqcSeperator(QDir::separator());
    QString strFullPath;
    //Ensure path is correct before use, this will handle translation of ~ if used!
    const char* cpszFolder = strCopy.toLatin1().data();
    wordexp_t exp_result;
    if ( wordexp(cpszFolder, &exp_result, 0) == 0 ) {
        char** ppszFullPath = exp_result.we_wordv;

        if ( ppszFullPath != nullptr ) {
            strFullPath = *ppszFullPath;
            QFileInfo info(strFullPath);

            if ( info.isDir() == true && strFullPath.endsWith(cqcSeperator) != true ) {
                strFullPath += cqcSeperator;
            }
        }
    }
    return strFullPath;
}
```

If strFolder contains:

```
~/XMLMPAM/config/form.xml
```

Then the function works and ~ is replaced with the actual user folder location, however is strFolder contains:

```
~/XMLMPAM 2/config/form.xml
```

Which also exists, the function fails and I can see when debugging that:

```
char** ppszFullPath = exp_result.we_wordv;
```

Points to:

```
/Users/sy/XMLMPAM
```

Which is my user profile folder but with the wrong folder name.  Why?

Comment: That's normal shell behavior. Any path with a space in it needs to be put in a single or double quoted string.

Comment: Yes, thank you, fixed by changing initialisation of strCopy to QString strCopy("\"" + strFolder + "\"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actually fix for this:

```
QString clsDebugService::strGetUserFolder(QString strFolder) {
    QString strCopy(strFolder);
    if ( strCopy.indexOf(" ") != -1 ) {
    //Ensure any spaces in the path are escaped
        strCopy.replace(" ", "\\ ");
    } else if ( strCopy.isEmpty() ) {
        strCopy = "~";
    }
    const QChar cqcSeperator(QDir::separator());
    QString strFullPath;
    //Ensure path is correct before use, this will handle translation of ~ if used!
    const char* cpszFolder = strCopy.toLatin1().data();
    wordexp_t exp_result;
    if ( wordexp(cpszFolder, &exp_result, 0) == 0 ) {
        char** ppszFullPath = exp_result.we_wordv;

        if ( ppszFullPath != nullptr ) {
            strFullPath = *ppszFullPath;
            QFileInfo info(strFullPath);

            if ( info.isDir() == true && strFullPath.endsWith(cqcSeperator) != true ) {
                strFullPath += cqcSeperator;
            }
        }
    }
    return strFullPath;
}
```